# jquery snap draggable to wrapper

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I drag horizontally a larger-than-browser div but want it to snap to the wrapper when reaching the end left and right. I can not do it with "containment" as the dragging is not working properly when the dragged div is larger than its containment:

```
$( "#dragable" ).draggable({ cursor: "e-resize", axis: "x", containment: "document" });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBVYT/320/

For this reason I remove the "containment" but then the dragged div is going out of the browser window:

```
$( "#dragable" ).draggable({ cursor: "e-resize", axis: "x" });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBVYT/325/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By controlling the drag event, you can prevent the draggable from moving out of the margins:
See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/hfkKp/)
Here are the options with the drag event function:

```
$( "#dragable" ).draggable({
    cursor: "e-resize"
    , axis: "x" 
    , drag: function(event, ui) {
        var $container = $(this).closest(".wrap");
        var container_left = $container.position().left;
        var container_right = $container.position().left + $container.width();
        var drag_left = ui.offset.left;
        var drag_right = ui.offset.left + $(this).width();
        if (drag_left > container_left) {
            return false;
        };
        if (drag_right < container_right) {
            return false;
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great for my purpose.

I only have a question on the lines

//event.preventDefault();
//event.stopPropagation();

as I want to understand the code - what does this stand for? 

Thanks again.

Comment: @peer, well, first I experimented with preventDefault and stopPropagation, but in the end I found that returning false from the drag function is sufficient to prevent the drag. So I commented out those lines. Hope that clarifies your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I would like to revert the container left and right. I tried to change the "return false;" with animate, but it's not doing what I want - to snap the dragged area to the container left and right. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is when I put $(this).stop().animate({ left: 0 }); instead of return false; in the line it reverts the div to the centre and not to the the container edge.

Answer (score 0):

What you have similar in the API is `revert` -  http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert or you can use in similar fashion jQuery's `.animate()`

For instance on **drop**

`wrapX+wrapWidth < draggableX + draggableW` which is `wrapEndX < draggableEndX` and you've crossed the right edge so revert it back to where it started or other work out would be animate it at the end  - the maximum value possible.

It's similar with the left edge.

You'll need to write your own logic, but it seems so anyway

Comment: The problem is when I put $(this).stop().animate({ left: 0 }); instead of return false; in the above code it reverts the div to the centre and not to the the container edge.

Comment: Don't know what you're doing it works fine with me http://jsfiddle.net/xBVYT/329/

Comment: Your example shows the problem - if I use the stop:function() the draggable always returns to CENTER. It will be the same with revert: true. I want the end of the draggable to return to the edge of the screen. It should be possible to view the draggable without reverting to CENTER, but when the left/right end of the draggable reaches the end of .wrap (width:100%;) it should return to it. I have tried with the above code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xBVYT/332/ The problems are that 1. the draggable returns to CENTER and 2. the reverting is triggered before I release the mouse.

Comment: It's in the center because your container `#drag` div is centered. See those `left:50%` you have centered it and now complaining that it's not at the left side!?! How is it that I'm more aware of your code or you don't know what you're doing at all? You can see in my example in my previous post above how to implement animation after the drag is finished so it triggers at the right time.

Comment: Here's an idea how to return it to the edge.
http://jsfiddle.net/xBVYT/337/ <br/>
http://jsfiddle.net/xBVYT/337/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I am not complaining at all, I am merely pointing what my problem is. I know it is centered and I want it to be so. But the problem is that on stop:function() the dragged returns to center. Imagine I will have all my content in the dragged div and what I want is that the user may drag and review the content without after each drag to be returned to the center. When the left or right edge is reached the dragged content should revert to the left or right part of the screen respectively. This is my problem :) I will try with your code.